# ionic custom directive scope

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am creating a directive in ionic app, and trying to load templateurl based on a parameter. altough the attribute exists when using console log, when trying to use it, ionic returns error:

```
ionic.bundle.js:26794 TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
```

this is my directive:

```
.directive('card', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: function(element, attrs) {console.log(attrs);
      return 'views/types/' . attrs.type;
    },
    scope: {
      item: '=',
    },
    controller: function($scope) {
      console.log($scope);
    }
}});
```

HTML:

```
<card ng-repeat="note in notes" item="note" type="plaintext"></card>
```

Comment: https://github.com/driftyco/ng-cordova/issues/60